# Call a stored-procedure mysql in django

Tags: mysql, django, stored-procedures

I am using a procedure I have written in MySQL that I want to call in Django but I am just receiving an error : " AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'stored_results' " I can't find why is cursor has no attribute, all the info I get about calling a procedure with python goes with the code 'cursor.stored_results()'.
Do you have an idea ?

My procedure is :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ProcTime`(IN in_date int, OUT somme int)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
SELECT SUM(tot) INTO somme FROM(
SELECT Habitat, COUNT(DISTINCT(Transect)) AS tot FROM MyTable 
WHERE Year = @in_date 
GROUP BY Habitat
) AS t ; 
END
```

And I am calling it in my views :

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
args = ['2004', 0]
cursor.callproc('ProcTime', args)
for result in cursor.stored_results():
        print(result.fetchall())
```

Thanks !!

Comment: I know this is possible with SQL Server, so I assume it is possible with MySQL. But why not use the ORM? It's Django's killer feature.

Comment: Have you tried calling without `stored_results()` ? Like `result = cursor.callproc('ProcTime', args)`

Comment: @Ahtisham yes, it is just returning '['2004', 0]' so the args I put in

Comment: @FlipperPA Why not but I didn't find anything about procedures in django ORM and the idea is to make my procedure interactive through a user request. Maybe you know more than me about ORM and if it's possible ?